# Click-away event in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've two Div's on my page. one is parent div, another div as pop-up.
Currently pop-up is shown/hide on click of parent div or clicking on button inside pop-up window.

How can I achieve that pop-up will be closed when I click away (anywhere outside pop-up and parent div) ? is there any event mechanism already provided ? if yes, How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another div with full width and height and z-index bigger that other content and less than pop up. Show that div whenever the pop up is showed. Then you can add this div an click event so when the user click on that div it means that it's outside of pop up.

Here is an [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sx0mjwe1/59/) for that made with jquery just to give you the idea how to make it .
Here is another one with Angular [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mb6o4yd1/491/)

Comment: Why not `.show()` & `.hide()` instead of changing the display mode manually?

Comment: pop up is coming for menu list - so content  page is changing dynamically. I'll never know on which page the user will see the pop-up by clicking parent div.

Comment: @Rinecamo it's the same thing. But it doesn't matter you can give this overlay div position absolute and left:0; top:0; and it will show always in the window no matter where you are and how much you have scrolled or anything else. You want to make this with jquery events or angular ?

Comment: @edisoni.1337 - angularJS

Comment: something like this is needed. Thank You for fiddle. :)